# How do I disable grid row click in adminhtml product catalog?

Tags: magento2

How do I disable grid click? So I can only click "Edit" link.

This is the grid in adminhtml: [image]

Here are all the places where getRowUrl($row) function is:

[image]

I've tried changing the function in `vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Grid.php`to `return false;`, and afterwards recompiling/deploy static content, but it doesn't work:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Check this path

```
vendor\magento\module-catalog\Block\Adminhtml\Product\Grid.php
```

you need to override this file and update below function as:

```
public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return "javascript&colon;void(0)";
    }

OR
public function getRowUrl($row)
    {
        return false;
    }
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Hmm, I tried this already, in vendor/magento/module-catalog/Block/Adminhtml/Product/Grid.php on line 439. I also ran setup:di:compile. Here is a picture of all the places where there is a getRowUrl function: https://imgur.com/a/fiXDoih

Comment: Also, if I want to override the file, where should I copy the file to? Thanks

Comment: Please, do you know how?